# Mathematical convention for writing products using dots

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

What would be the appropriate way of writing the following products involving numbers and variables (in LaTeX)?

- $2^{3}\cdot 5^{17}\cdot 11^{2}\cdot (x+y)$ $\qquad\text{or}\qquad$ $2^{3}\cdot 5^{17}\cdot 11^{2}(x+y)$
- $2^{3}\cdot 5^{17}\cdot 11^{2}\cdot x$ $\qquad\text{or}\qquad$ $2^{3}\cdot 5^{17}\cdot 11^{2}x$

Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Both seem OK, but for **consistency**, the ones on the **left** are better

Comment: @Shailesh do you mean on the left? I'd say left for the same reason of consistency

Comment: @Stahl corrected !

Comment: I prefer the ones on the right, but both are acceptable. And $2^35^{17}11^2x$ etc. is better yet.

Answer (score 1):

The use of conjunction, that is writing $ab$ instead of $a\cdot b$, is common to denote multiplication. So, any notation you use is likely to be understood, and both are common:
\begin{align}
a\cdot b\cdot cx && \text{or} && a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot x
\end{align}
is fine. The same goes for
\begin{align}
a\cdot b\cdot c(x+y) && \text{or} && a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot (x+y).
\end{align}

Comment: I would not use any of these save under very unusual circumstances: $abcx$ and $abc(x+y)$ are far preferable in almost all cases. Obviously the dot (or parentheses) is needed in $2\cdot 3$, but it is wholly superfluous in $2a$ or $ab$; $2^k3^\ell$ is a borderline case, though even there I prefer the version without the dot.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott agreed